# How do you edit the front page of a Hugo website and add new content?

Tags: hugo

I've clicked "Deploy to Netlify" here:

https://jamstack.org/generators/hugo/

and downloaded the github repo.

How do you now edit the front page?

Following the instructions in the Hugo Quick Start:

`hugo new site quickstart` just creates a new site

`hugo new content posts/my-first-post.md` just gives me an error: `Error: no existing content directory configured for this project`

https://gohugo.io/getting-started/usage/ doesn't seem to have anything on how to edit your home page or add content.

https://gohugo.io/getting-started/directory-structure/ seems to be missing directories - e.g. I have no `content/` directory.

Any suggestions on what I need to do with Hugo?

Alternatively, is there another, simpler system than Hugo that works out of the box?

Comment: Run `hugo version` and make sure you are using Hugo **Extended** v0.112.0 or later. Also, if you are on Windows, make sure you are **not** using CMD or Windows PowerShell. Then carefully step through the Quick Start https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start and it should work. I just tested the Quick Start using Hugo Extended v0.118.2 and Git Bash (a Windows bash shell) and it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. It seems like the Netlify template is missing some directories. Either start a new site with `hugo new site quickstart`, or create the `content/` and `content/post/` directory manually.

Then, you can set the front page by using the [homepage template](https://gohugo.io/templates/homepage/).

Alternatively, you can also create a regular page and set the url. To do this, run `hugo new content homepage.md` and add `url: /` to the front matter like so:

```
---
title: your title
date: <some date here>
draft: true
url: /
---
```